# Using unittesting framework for data validation

Tags: matlab, unit-testing

In our applications, we have to setup a data validation routine to be applied on set of data we are using.

More precisely, for a given set of data, we would like to perform a set of checks on it in order to verify its consistency. For instance, given dynamical properties of an object such as:

- mass
- center of gravity
- inertia matrix

we would like to verify that:

- mass is positive
- inertia matrix is symmetric
- inertia matrix is definite positive
- etc...

For this purpose, matlab unittest framework looks interesting, as it offers a whole set of checks and acceptance conditions. However, even with parametrized test, it seems not possible to have a test suite that can accept data to be checked as input, e.g. it seems not possible to write a parametrized test where the parameters are set when running the testsuite instead of within the class (as it is presented in the documentation).

I am wondering if I am missing something about unittest API or if it is definitely not possible to do so?

Comment: It's the idea of a unit test to check the behavior of your code in a known situation (including boundary cases). Why not just set up a *validateData()* routine and pass the input in?

Comment: This is not what unit-testing is!

Comment: I know that this is not unit-testing, but the framework as so many interesting features (esp. assertions, tolerances, report generation) that it would greatly reduce the amount of work for developing such validation routine

Comment: I am not sure I have my head around precisely what the problem is yet. Does @Mike Scannell's answer below help? It is true that test parameters can't be defined at runtime, but they can be defined dynamically by invoking a function that processes data and creates test parameters, which are then used in the test suite at runtime. In order to change the parameters you would need to restart MATLAB or call clear classes. Does this help get you going?

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar to what you're asking. It doesn't take a command line argument as input, but it does essentially run tests on a group of files in a directory. Here's a skeleton of some code to do that:

```
classdef checkMyData < matlab.unittest.TestCase

    properties(TestParameter)
        % just create a cell array of numbers, one for each file, for the test to iterate through
        filenum = num2cell(1:length(dir('\directory\where\data\is\*.mat')));
    end

    methods(Test)

        function genericFile(testCase,filenum)

            % get details on the file we're currently testing
            testDataPath = '\directory\where\data\is';
            testFiles = dir(fullfile(testDataPath,'*.mat'));
            filename = fullfile(testDataPath,testFiles(filenum).name);
            [~,nameonly,~] = fileparts(filename);

            % load data
            load(filename);

            % do some test
            testCase.verifyGreaterThanOrEqual(mass,[nameonly ': Mass is negative'])

        end

    end

end
```